# MAUI: Getting user secrets returns null

Tags: c#, visual-studio, maui

I did:

```
dotnet user-secrets init
```

then

```
dotnet user-secrets set "con" "123"
```

In my folder under:

```
/Users/juliustolksdorf/.microsoft/usersecrets/6b18f6d2-fda1-4673-b259-54176edbf6cc/secrets.json
```

I found a json secrets.json now containing my secret.

My csprof file now includes:

```
<UserSecretsId>6b18f6d2-fda1-4673-b259-54176edbf6cc</UserSecretsId>
```

And all I am trying in code is:

```
var con = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("con");
```

But null is returned.
Am I missing something? Seems like everything SHOULD be working...

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in support for this in .NET MAUI today, that's why it doesn't work unfortunately.

You can track the status in this issue: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/4408

There is also a mention of a way of implementing this in your project if you want to use this today. The key code is pasted below, taken from [here](https://github.com/maxkoshevoi/NureTimetable/blob/a67e7ed78cfc4de3512d8c36ac33fdefa48a8571/NureTimetable.Core/Models/Consts/Keys.cs), full credit to [Maksym](https://github.com/maxkoshevoi):

```cs
    public static class Keys
    {
        public static string SyncfusionLicenseKey => Configuration?.Value<string>(nameof(SyncfusionLicenseKey)) ?? throw new NullReferenceException(nameof(SyncfusionLicenseKey));
        public static string MicrosoftAppCenterKey => Configuration?.Value<string>(nameof(MicrosoftAppCenterKey)) ?? throw new NullReferenceException(nameof(MicrosoftAppCenterKey));
        public static string CistApiKey => Configuration?.Value<string>(nameof(CistApiKey)) ?? throw new NullReferenceException(nameof(CistApiKey));

        private static JObject? Configuration { get; } = GetConfiguration("secrets.json");

        private static JObject? GetConfiguration(string filePath)
        {
            Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            string? assemblyName = assembly.GetName().Name;
            using Stream? fileStream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream($"{assemblyName}.{filePath}");
            if (fileStream == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            using StreamReader sr = new(fileStream);
            string fileContent = sr.ReadToEnd();
            return JObject.Parse(fileContent);
        }
    }
```

Basically what this does is just load the json file as a manifest file and parse that.

You could maybe even make that code easier for .NET MAUI by using the [file system helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/file-system-helpers#bundled-files).

Comment: thanks man, but how do I use it? past it and execute GetConfig? Do I have to paste the file path?

Answer (score 0):

I came here looking for the same thing. I found a solution that worked on Windows, but not Android unfortunately.

```
static IConfiguration BuildConfiguration(string? prefix)
{
    var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();

    // Add configuration sources
    configurationBuilder.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
    configurationBuilder.AddUserSecrets<App>();
    configurationBuilder.AddEnvironmentVariables(prefix);

    return configurationBuilder.Build();
}
```

Add this to the project file:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables" Version="8.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="8.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets" Version="8.0.0" />
```

This is how I tested it:

```
static void CheckForValidApiKey(this IConfiguration configuration, string sectionName, string apiKey = "ApiKey")
{
    var section = configuration.GetSection(sectionName);
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(section[apiKey]))
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
}
```